# Track Form Fill Message Inside Div Class Using Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm trying to track a form fill message using Google Tag Manager (GTM) but I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out the trigger required to track the message.

Unsure if a element visibility trigger using a CSS Selector is require or if I used add an event listener to listen the for div class message instead and to apply a custom event instead. Both have failed to fire currently

[thank you message with div class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aInv4.png)

This is the CSS selector I tried in GTM [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wC9S3.png)

This is the event listener I tried [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wvj5A.png)

This is the site https://pulse-me.com and the web dev advised the form type is a contact form 7

Looking to any GTM experts that could lend there wisdom to help me overcome this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Many Thanks

Brett

Answer (score 0):

I saw your website and fillup a form (srry).
You can use this CSS seclector for Element Visibility:

Trigger: Element Visibility
Select CSS selector and paste the bellow Selector,
section#contact div.elementor-element.__contact_form.elementor-widget.elementor-widget-wpforms > div > div > div > p

Percent will be 5% or 10%.
Click: DOM changes.
That's it.

Comment: An invitation for people to contact you off-site for help isn't appropriate in an answer. Please don't do that.